# How do I print a `chrono` duration with units with Howard Hinnant's date.h?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have the following toy code:

```cpp
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main() {
    cout << microseconds(100);
};
```

But, it doesn't work because:

```
C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::chrono::milliseconds' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

But the [docs](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) for `date.h` list the specification:

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Rep, class Period>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os,
           const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& d);
```

which will use `get_units` to output appropriate units.

So, how can I properly use this overloaded `<<` operator?

Comment: Your code looks different from the example in [duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `operator<<` is inside the `date` namespace. Since neither of the operand types are from this namespace, argument-dependent lookup won't find it.

To use it you need either `using namespace date` or `using date::operator<<`.

Another issue in your code is that `microseconds` can only be constructed from an integer type, not floating point.